# Remove/cancel a particular product from all pending orders in admin

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order, order-grid, edit-order

I am doing a magento project in which i have to select all pending order at once and move to complete status from the order management page in admin.

I have done this modification and it is working fine. But the requirement is, while moving those orders to complete status, if the order consist of one particular product i have to remove that product or have to change the quantity to 0 and process it.

As a newbie to magento i fall short of logic's/ideas here. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When looping through your orders collection, loop through the products of the orders with `$order->getAllVisibleItems()`. This will give you a product object, then you'll be able to compare it against a certain SKU. The thing is, an order is kind of "set in stone", as in, it's a processed Quote. What you can do it refund the product, but I don't think you'll be able to "delete" it from the Order, unless you manually query your DB. What of the payment made for that product? Don't you have to refund it too?

Comment: Thank you. The site doesn't have any payment gateway. Its like getting orders from members and collecting the money offline when required.

Comment: Well it's gonna be easier for you then :) Have you tried what I suggested ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some analysis and googling i have achieved it using the below code,

```
$orderIds = $this->getRequest()->getPost('order_ids', array());  // get all order ids
$countCompleteOrder = 0;
$_resource = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product')->getResource();
$mailBody = '';
$mailSend = 0;
foreach ($orderIds as $orderId) {
    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
    //echo '<pre>'; print_r($order); exit;
    $customer = Mage::getModel("customer/customer")->load($order->getCustomerId());
    $items = $order->getAllItems();
    $pass = 0;
    $true = $k = 0;
    $items_count = count($items);
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        //echo '<pre>'; print_r($item); exit;
        $k++;
        if ($k == 1) {
            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());
            $cats = $product->getCategoryIds();
            $category_id = $cats[0];

            $_cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())->load($category_id);
        }

        $base_grand_total = $order->getBaseGrandTotal();

        $base_subtotal = $order->getBaseSubtotal();
        $base_tva = $order->getBaseTaxAmount();

        $grand_total = $order->getGrandTotal();

        $subtotal = $order->getSubtotal();
        $tva = $order->getTaxAmount();


        $base_subtotal_incl_tax = $order->getBaseSubtotalInclTax();

        $subtotal_incl_tax = $order->getSubtotalInclTax();

        $total_item_count = $order->getTotalItemCount();

        $minorderqty = $_resource->getAttributeRawValue($item->getProductId(), 'min_order_qty', Mage::app()->getStore());

        $report = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_sold_collection')
                ->addOrderedQty()
                ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'id'))
                ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', $item->getProductId())
                ->getFirstItem();
        $ordered_qty = intval($report->getOrderedQty());

        for ($i = 0; $i < $items_count; $i++) {
            if ($ordered_qty >= $minorderqty) {
                $true++;
            }
        }

        if (($ordered_qty < $minorderqty) && ($true > 0)) {
            $item_price = $item->getPrice();
            $item_tva = $item->getTaxAmount();
            if ($items_count > 1) {

                $item->delete();
                $order->setBaseGrandTotal($base_grand_total - $item_price - $item_tva);

                $order->setBaseSubtotal($base_subtotal - $item_price);

                $order->setBaseTaxAmount($base_tva - $item_tva);

                $order->setGrandTotal($grand_total - $item_price - $item_tva);

                $order->setSubtotal($subtotal - $item_price);

                $order->setTaxAmount($tva - $item_tva);


                $order->setBaseSubtotalInclTax($base_subtotal_incl_tax - $item_price);

                $order->setSubtotalInclTax($subtotal_incl_tax - $item_price);

                $order->setTotalItemCount(count($items) - 1);

                $order->save();

                $mailSend++;
            }
        }
    }

}
```